# convert price per PU in price per ton

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Quite basic calculation, but my client insist on telling I am calculating wrong while I am quite sure that my calculation is correct.

Given the following variables:

- weight in kg per packing unit
- packing unit
- price in EUR per 100

What I need is the price per ton.

Given the following values:

- kg per PU: 0,45
- PU: 500
- € per 100: 0,98

I used the following calculation:

$$
\begin{align}
     & 0,98 € \times {1000 kg \over {0,45 kg \over {500 pcs \over 100pcs }}} \\
= \; & 0,98 € \times {1000kg \over {0,45kg \over 5}} \\
= \; & 0,98 € \times {1000 kg \over 0,09 kg} \\
= \; & 0,98 € \times 11.111,\overline1 kg \\
= \; & 10888,\overline8 €
\end{align}$$

Would anyone please be so kind to check if that is correct?

Comment: ton or tonne?  0.45kg is that really one pound (US)?

Comment: I meant german "Tonne" = 1.000 kg.

Comment: But is that also what your client means?

Comment: Yes, it is. The data description was wrong. The source contained the weight per 100 pcs, not per packing unit. I'll accept your answer as the calculation is correct and your calculation confirms my one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

so it's 0.98 for 100 and there's 500 in a packing unit = 4.90 euro.

the packing unit at 0.45kg is a pound (approximately) and there's 2000 pounds in a US ton

so I get about 9800 euro using approximate US measure.